# JavaFX - Making GridPane take up all available space in BorderPane

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

I'm using the following code to create a simple grid of buttons for a calculator:

```
    BorderPane rootNode = new BorderPane();

    GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
    rootNode.setCenter(gridPane);

    int counter = 1;
    for(int row = 3; row > 0; row--)
        for(int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
            Button button = new Button("" + counter++);
            button.setOnAction(this);
            gridPane.add(button, col, row);
        }
    gridPane.add(new Button("R"), 0, 4);
    gridPane.add(new Button("0"), 1, 4);
```

(Wanted to post an image of how it looks here, but I don't have enough reputation points to be allowed to do so)

The GridPane ends up being tiny and crammed up in the upper left corner, but I want it to take up all available space in the BorderPane's center region (that would be the entire window in this case). I've tried messing around with a bunch of things like various setSize methods, but havn't had much luck.

Comment: As it states in the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/GridPane.html): *If an application needs a particular row or column to grow if there is extra space, it may set its **grow priority** on the `RowConstraints` or `ColumnConstraints`* (scroll to **Row/Column Sizing**). They have an example in the docs. Create constraint objects and add them to the pane

Answer (score 2):

Your `GridPane` is already taking all the space available to it i.e. the entire `Borderpane`. Its the GridCells which are not using the space available to the GridPane.

You can make use of the `Hgrow` and `Vgrow` options available in the GridPane to make the cells take up the entire space available.

Here is an example which uses `setHgrow` to use the entire width available to the GridPane. You may add the same for the Height.

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Priority;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        BorderPane rootNode = new BorderPane();
        rootNode.setMinSize(300, 300);
        rootNode.setStyle("-fx-background-color: RED;");
        GridPane gridPane = new GridPane();
        gridPane.setStyle("-fx-background-color: BLUE;");
        rootNode.setCenter(gridPane);

        int counter = 1;
        for (int row = 3; row > 0; row--)
            for (int col = 0; col < 3; col++) {
                Button button = new Button("" + counter++);
                gridPane.add(button, col, row);
                GridPane.setHgrow(button, Priority.ALWAYS);
            }
        Button r = new Button("R");
        gridPane.add(r, 0, 4);
        GridPane.setHgrow(r, Priority.ALWAYS);
        Button r0 = new Button("0");
        gridPane.add(r0, 1, 4);
        GridPane.setHgrow(r0, Priority.ALWAYS);
        Scene scene = new Scene(rootNode);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I missunderstood the question.

The Buttons are just too small, so not taking all the space they have in the borderpane? The width of a button depends on the size of the text it has. You just write a number in it so they are pretty small then. Use button.setPrefWidth(Integer.MAX_VALUE) and they use all the width they can get!

Comment: Changing it to (int row = 0; row < 3; row++) only changes which button gets assigned which number. Sadly it dosn't do anything else for me.

Comment: You can add nodes to a `GridPane` in any order you like.